# Passing arrays between methods and calling them in main

Tags: java, arrays

I want to pass an array from one method to another and call that method on the array. However, it shows where `increaseCost()` is not applicable for arguments. How would I fix this code?

I'm trying to pass `double[] price` to `increaseCost()`:

```
import java.util.*;
public class LabQuiz3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initialize();
        increaseCost();
    }
    static void initialize() {
        String[] name=new String[10];
        System.out.println("Name of the grocery? ");
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            String a = scan.next();
            name[i]=a;
        }
        scan.close();
        double[] price=new double[10];
        System.out.println("Price of each grocery? ");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int j=0; j < 10; j++) {
            double b=sc.nextDouble();
            price[j]=b;
        }
        sc.close();
    }
    static void increaseCost(double[] price) {
        for (int c=0; c <10; c++) {
            double k=price[c] * .07;
            price[c]=k;
        }
        System.out.println(price);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main method you have to get the `prices` from the `initialize()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] prices = initialize();
    increaseCost(prices);
}
```

And in the initialize method you have to return the `prices` array:

```
static double[] initialize() {
   //all your code
   ...
   return price;
}
```

A few other things to remark:

- maybe rename your `price` variable to `prices` as it is a list of prices
- you are mixing a lot of concerns (reading, printing, keeping state, etc.), normally you should keep those things separated
- reading in the names of the groceries and the prices should probably be a seperate concern and reside in an own method, you lose track of the names since you are not returning them in any way
- the for loop is strangely formatted, normally the full loop goes on one line

There are other things, but it's probably just a lab quiz.

Comment: But if I turn void initialize() into double[] initialize(), wouldn't it lose the String[] name?

Comment: Yes, that is what I said in the remarks, you probably want to keep track of the `name` too, so you want to have something like `initializeNames()` and `initializePrices()`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!

Comment: I created a little pastebin for you [here](http://pastebin.com/F8h3f3Xw)